# Should i just use html sanitizer on "rich html values"?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, xss

Do i need to sanitize all string values passed to my controller or just rich html like editors?

What about input , type text fields?

```
<input type="text" name"test1" value="<script></script>" />


public ActionResult TestAction(string test1){ //save in db }
```

Comment: Probably ideal to use sanitization based on the data type; i.e. if you expect only numbers, if you expect html, if you expect alpha-num, special chars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Always sanitize data being sent to the server. You don't want anyone to arbitrarily send data to your server of any type. Some HTML tags, such as `<script>` elements, can be harmful. You don't want the user storing JavaScript code in your content pages as it could be malicious for other users.